# does pipenv supports custom conflicts resolution?

Tags: python, pipenv

In my organization there is a lot of packages.
We would like to work with pinned version but we usually get transitive conflicts.
i.e. A1-> (B1, C1), B1 -> C2

as we know, In pip we get the first installed
and in pipenv we get a conflict error

what we want to do as policy is to resolve it by an internal policy such as: if the conflict is on release number, take the larger one (not the latest!) if not fail.

1. Does pipenv have a plugin hook to inject a custom conflict resolver like gradle [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)
2. Can pipenv output the full dependencies graph report including all the conflicts it found. I mean not graph of what is installed but graph of what would have been installed.
   This way I can analyze it, create new pipfile and reinstall.

I already tried "graph" and "graph --reverse" after install --skip-lock but only got the graph of what was "pip like" installed without the conflicts.